# Python subprocess.run() only runs commands up to first newline

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'm looking into a bug on some software I use and I'm seeing unexpected behavior from python's `subprocess.run()`. When a command string is provided, it seems to only run the command up until the first newline (on windows). For example:

Example 1 - No newline:

```
python -c "import subprocess; from subprocess import PIPE; call = subprocess.run('''echo out 1 && echo out 2''', check=True, stdout=PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,); print(call.stdout.decode('utf-8'))"
```

Output:

```
out 1
out 2
```

Example 2 - Same script except 1 newline in the command string:

```
python -c "import subprocess; from subprocess import PIPE; call = subprocess.run('''echo out 1
 && echo out 2''', check=True, stdout=PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,); print(call.stdout.decode('utf-8'))"
```

Output:

```
out  1
```

I thought it might be an issue with reading the output, but I tried writing to a file before and after the newline, and it only worked before, so I think indeed the problem is that it only executes commands up to the newline.

How do I fully execute strings with newlines in them?

UPDATE:

Technically, I think below is the case that I need to work. The above case has `&&` between the two echoes. The case below does not, as if they were two lines of an executing script:

```
python -c "import subprocess; from subprocess import PIPE; call = subprocess.run('''echo out 1
 echo out 2''', check=True, stdout=PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,); print(call.stdout.decode('utf-8'))"
```

On Windows this prints 1 line, but on Ubuntu it prints 2.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered if you set subprocess to use pwsh instead of cmd it fixes the problem:

Set the environment variable `COMSPEC` to `pwsh` instead of `cmd`. For example in powershell:

```
$oldComSpec = $env:COMSPEC
try {
   $env:COMSPEC="$(Get-Command pwsh | select -ExpandProperty Source) -NoProfile"
   someScript.ps1
} finally {
   $env:COMSPEC = $oldComSpec

}
```

So far this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why the rules of triple quotes didn't work here, but capping that broken string with the appropriate quotes seems to have fixed the issue. Maybe python -c doesn't handle triple quotes inside the string being passed because the string itself is considered in the same way triple quotes are? just my guess, hope this helps.

```
python -c "import subprocess; from subprocess import PIPE; call = subprocess.run('echo out 1'
'&& echo out 2', check=True, stdout=PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,); print(call.stdout.decode('utf-8'))"
```

Comment: python appears to concatenate strings with whitespace between them. So `print('dog' 'cat')` prints `dogcat`. In your example, the string you pass to `run()` is `echo out 1&& echo out 2`. It doesn't have a newline in it, so the whole thing runs. I'm looking for a way to run a string with a newline in it.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, you want the command line run to have a newline character in it? essentially the same as telling it to press the enter button before running echo out 2?  edit: I just saw the update to you're initial question, that does seem to be weird that you get different results between ubuntu and windows, maybe this isn't a bug exclusive to python? I'll run some more tests

Comment: what exactly is the restraints to this problem, what is the subprocess command doing in your use case exactly?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize/issues/206) is the context. It's for running a yaml multi-line string. But my latest comment shows a workaround.